# How to run External collector from Scollector?

Tags: python, opentsdb, scollector

I am trying to run external sample.py script in ***/path-to-scollector/collectors/0***  folder from scollector.

**scollector.toml:**

```
Host = "localhost:0"
ColDir="//path-to-scollector//collectors//"
BatchSize=500
DisableSelf=true
```

command to run scollector:

```
scollector-windows-amd64.exe -conf scollector.toml -p
```

But I am not getting the sample.py metrics in the output. It is expected to run continuosly and print output to cnosole. Also when I am running:

```
 scollector-windows-amd64.exe -conf scollector.toml -l
```

my external collector is not listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running scollector on linux machine the above solution works well. But with windows its a bit tricky. Since scollector running on windows can only identify batch files. So we need to do a little extra work for windows.

**create external collector :-**
It can be written in any language python,java etc. It contains the main code to get the data and print to console.

Example *my_external_collector.py*

**create a wrapper batch script :-**
*wrapper_external_collector.bat*.

Trigger *my_external_collector.py* inside *wrapper_external_collector.bat*.

```
python path_to_external/my_external_collector.py
```

You can pass arguments to the script also.Only disadvantage is we need to maintain two scripts.

Answer (score 2):

In your scollector.toml, You should one line as below,
`Filter=["sample.py "]` .

in your sample.py,  you need this line
`#!/usr/bin/python`